# Vuejs simple dynamic v-show using index and falsey v-if to toggle elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

What's the best solution to do `v-show` to toggle elements based on `index`, I managed to do the toggling part however when you click the element that's currently open it won't close.

```
<div v-for="(btn, index) in dataArray">
      <button @click="toggle(index)">{{ btn.name }}</button>
      <p v-show="isOpenIndex === index"> {{ btn.desc }} </p>
    </div>
```

If I added falsey condition, it closes the open one when if you click another button but it doesn't open the element you've clicked

```
<div v-for="(btn, index) in dataArray">
  <button @click="toggle(index)">{{ btn.name }}</button>
  <p v-show="isOpenIndex === index" v-if="isOpen"> {{ btn.desc }} </p>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/256958/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 1:**
As @MrNew said, the ternary operator in the `toggle` method is enough:

```
...
methods: {
    toggle: function(index){
        this.isOpenIndex = ( this.isOpenIndex == index ) ? null : index;
    }
}
```

**Original answer:**

Add both conditions to your `toggle` method: if `isOpenIndex` is defined, check if it matches the current element's `index` to turn it off (return it to `null`) and if it doesn't, set it to `index`. If it is not defined, the set it to `index`:

```
methods: {
    toggle: function(index){
        if( this.isOpenIndex !== null ){
           this.isOpenIndex = ( this.isOpenIndex == index ) ? null : index;
        } else {
           this.isOpenIndex = index;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are using `null` and an zero-based value (`index`), don't forget to use the strict equality operator (`!==`) to avoid errors with falsey values.

Comment: Yeah thanks, already fixed it :D will accept your answer anyway. The `else` condition isn't really necessary `this.isOpenIndex = index === this.isOpenIndex? null : index;` as this is enough.